# Fragment and null getActivity after onAttach

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I'm trying to understand under what circumstances can getActivity() return null in a fragment AFTER onAttach. I typically start an async task in onCreate or onCreateView inside my fragments but I'm getting error reports indicating sometimes getActivity() is null when the async task finishes. Error reports are coming in via crashlytics but can't reproduce them.

The async tasks are "blocking" - I display a modal non-dismissable progress bar. Also rotation is prevented by calling setRequestedOrientation.

I'm using v4 support Fragment and FragmentActivity. Fragments are set to retain state.

What am I missing? Are there other config changes that may cause the fragment to be detached?

I tried temporarily enabling rotation and the dev option to destroy activity after leaving it but still can't reproduce this...

Here's some of the relevant code inside one of my fragments, in this case it would sometimes break with an NPE at `activity.dismissSpinner`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    checkIfLoggedIn();
}

public void checkIfLoggedIn() {
    LoginActivity activity = (LoginActivity)getActivity();
    activity.showSpinner("Connecting, please wait...");

    AsyncTask<String, Void, JsonResponse> asyncTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, JsonResponse>() {
        protected JsonResponse doInBackground(String... notused) {
            return cmsServer().getCurrentUser(getActivity());
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JsonResponse result) {               
            LoginActivity activity = (LoginActivity)getActivity();
            activity.dismissSpinner();
            //...more stuff here
        }
    };
    asyncTask.execute();
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code here to understand the situation clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you stop/cancel your `AsyncTask` if your app goes to background or is paused?

Consider the following scenario: your AsyncTask is executed, and when prompted with the progress bar, the user decides to do other stuff while she waits for the task to complete. She does so by pressing the home button. Alas, this might destroy the fragment and the activity. The running `AsyncTask` knows nothing about it, and when done, `getActivity()` method invocations (or local variables pointing to a non-existent Activity) may as well return `null`, causing your app to crash.

Comment: Well, I don't want to cancel it since I don't want to redo it when the user gets back...My best guess at this point is exactly this scenario. I think the alternative would be to be extra-defensive when the async task completes and check if the fragment is still attached.

Comment: You could very well do the `null` or `isAdded()` checks, but your `AsyncTask` would only waste resources. I’m not entirely sure I understand the “I don't want to redo it when the user gets back” - if the user isn’t logged in, you would have to retry the login regardless, right?

Comment: Good point. The login is only one example of this pattern. In other cases, I'm retrieving some (potentially large) content. I was thinking I wouldn't want to redo that request, but maybe it makes more sense for the user to come back to the same screen and the same state...

Answer (score -2):

The `Fragment`life cycle is as follows

[image: Fragment life cycle]

According to `Fragment` life-cycle `onCreate()` and `onCreateView()`are called  before the `Activity` creation. so when we call `getActivity()` in these methods in returns null.
so instead of starting the async task in the `onCreateView()` start it in `onStart()` or `onResume()` so that `getActivity()` returns the exact `Activity` reference.

For more details [click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: That is incorrect. onCreate and onCreateView are called AFTER onAttach  and the activity exists at that point. It's onCreate method may have not finished, but it exists and mActivity in the fragment is non null. Quoting: onActivityCreated(Bundle) tells the fragment that its activity has completed its own Activity.onCreate().